# Initializing 2 objects that require each other as parameters

Tags: c#, oop

I have code following the template :

```
class A
{
    private B _b;

    public A(B b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }
}

class B
{
    private A _a;

    public B(A a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }
}
```

Is this considered bad design?
What is the simplest way to initialize both classes besides adding a method like `void SetA(A a)` in B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this considered bad design?

Who knows (it depends on your actual use case...), but if your code is like your code snippet, maybe you're trying to use [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) over [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29), when inheritance would work better.

Think about the following sentences:

- A wolf has an animal (really?).
- A car has an engine (true!);
- A office chair has a chair (really?).
- ... and so on.

Actually I doubt that a `B` could have an `A`, but I'm sure `B` could be an `A`.

In the other hand, if you used `A` or `B` class identifiers just to show us a code sample, but in your code your classes can't be expressed with the **is** verb (for example `B` is an `A`), then maybe your design is the right track.

BTW, if `A` and `B` are a **1:1** associtation, where one `A` has a `B` and one `B` has an `A`, if the association makes sense, it's not a bad design per se...  For example, an `User` entity has an `UserProfile`, and an `UserProfile` has an owner `User`:

```
public class User 
{
     public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
     public User OwnerUser { get; set; }
}
```

> What is the simplest way to initialize both classes besides adding a
>   method like void SetA(A a) in B?

The simplest approach is using read-write properties (that is, properties with getter and setter) and set them once their class has been already instantiated, or use constructors. Actually there's no *simplest* way, but there's **the most appropiate way depending on your actual use case**.

### Summary

Use inheritance if you can express the class relationship using the **is** verb (i.e. a `Cat` is an `Animal`), while you use composition when you can express the so-called relationship using the **has** verb (i.e. a `House` has a `TV`).